# What are the benefits of using gradient boosting machines in terms of variance and bias?

Tags: machine-learning, variance, boosting, overfitting

In two datasets that are composed of the same sample number, about 1500, but with different features. The first dataset has 15 predictive features and the second has 40.

Now for someone who is training a classifier, but is constantly facing overfitting (high AUCs in the training model and low AUCs in the test model), one would want to lower the variance, since overfitting is basically a high variance and low bias.

How does the gradient-boosting algorithm deal with this problem? I mean, some algorithms are known to skew toward high variance and some are toward low variance. For GBM, which one is it?